# How to determine if a probabilities is exact or approximate

Tags: probability

I encounter a question:
A consumer agency surveyed all 2500 families living in a small town to collect data on the number of television sets owned by them. The following table lists the frequency distribution of the data collected by this agency.

The question then ask to draw a probability distribution table. It then asked if the probabilities listed in the table is exact or approximate for various outcomes. My question is what are the indicators that determine if it's exact or approximate?

Comment: Are you able to post the frequency distribution table as an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just get the answer. Actually there is no need to refer to the table. Since the data collected exactly all the families (population), thus the probabilities calculated from it should be exact. To determine if the possibility is exact, check if the data collected is in sample or population.